# password to remote devices in an ssh session

Tags: bash, function, ssh, telnet, remote-server

I have been using below two functions to login some remote devices. below code works fine for telnet, i.e. once the SERVICECHECK function is called, it initiates LOGIN function and echoes multiple commands on remote devices, first command being the password.. recently I had to move to SSH, and with SSH, I tried the below options and it is reaching and stays at password prompt.

> ssh -T -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $myuser@$IP -p $PORT

I tried above command with sshpass -p "$mypass" utility and it also worked fine, I could login the remote devices and echo multiple commands and got the output. currently, I do not have sshpass utility, and while trying to login using below code, and echoing password inside the function seems not working. Can someone please help with password, how I can send password to the remote device? 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13317/kenster maybe Kenster can answer this?

```
LOGIN()

{
(
 ssh -T -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $myuser@$IP -p $PORT
)
}

SERVICECHECK()
{
(
 echo "$mypass"  
 echo .. # some commands
 echo "logout"
) | LOGIN $IP $PORT
}

SERVICECHECK
```

Comment: ssh will not accept the password on stdin. You need either sshpass or expect to script the interactions. However, why don't you set up ssh keys so you don't need a password to log in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't SSH work with a piped password on stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159491/why-doesnt-ssh-work-with-a-piped-password-on-stdin)

Comment: Hi, it's not the same as I'm using -T option and I'm not receiving this error: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.... Rather I'm getting a terminal and prompt for password... Regrading ssh keys, I'll have a look, but my scenario is that I have multiple terminals using same IP but different random port, and virtually I have around 200k or more end devices to connect to, not sure if ssh key would work?